# Java threads in Queue, once done with task, need to sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I have the following case to model

the program starts by querying the DB per received parameters and understanding the amount of tasks to be run.

Threads queue with some fixed max threads is defined to execute the tasks. Each task starts a flow that can have different configuration and can take different time. Once a tasks completes, each has a configurable sleep time.

Once a task sleeps, it cannot block a spot on the execution queue. The execution queue must continue with tasks that are ready to execute

I find it hard to code for some reason (mainly due to the last requirement)
Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use some `ExecutorService`, e.g., `Executors.newCachedThreadPool(...)` or `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(...)`?

Comment: That is not enough. Say I use a fixed thread pool with fixed amount of threads, for example 10. Now say I have 100 tasks to execute repeatedly. Once a task is over and I get an object back (callable), I need to determine if this task needs to sleep and for how long. For the example sake, lets say I need to sleep for 3 minutes on one of the tasks before submitting it to the execution queue (the one with 10 threads). While this tasks sleeps, 10 executer threads must continue running other tasks in the queue. Point is - the sleep time on a task must be done outside of the main Execution Queue.

Comment: Tasks run business logic, once done, other tasks take their spot in Queue. Once a task is over sleeping, it is re-submitted to the main Execution Queue.

Comment: Can you just add `Thread.sleep(...)` to your `Callable#call(...)` body?

Comment: That will put the thread from main Execution Queue to sleep. I wish to have the sleep time outside of execution time if you understand what I mean. So a thread from Execution Queue get a task to execute - it will execute Business Logic part and release the thread for next task. The previous task will sleep (on some other thread?) and once ready, will join the Execution Queue (to the end of it)

Comment: Hmm, `sleep` will put to sleep a thread from pool which is serving that task. Using you example, one of 10 threads will sleep. You still be able to submit new tasks to pool. Be aware, though, that if you submit faster than your tasks are finished and sleep over, you'll eventually run out of memory.

Comment: As I mentioned, I dont want that behavior. Every task is configured with sleep time (that vary in length) and once business logic is done, it needs to sleep. Putting the task itself to sleep will starve the main Execution Queue (if it is limited in threads - which it is).

Comment: Then, sorry, I don't understand which thread should be put to sleep -- you don't want this for executor's thread serving a task and there's no other candidate, right? Or do you want just to ensure that tasks of the same kind can be put into executor queue with an interval between them (i.e., at least X seconds must pass between two instances of same task, where X depends on task type?)

Comment: Again, a task is always the same. Each task has business logic to be executed, and then it needs to sleep for some time (configurable for that task). Once the program starts, it will check how many tasks it needs to execute. for example 100 tasks. The Execution Queue has a fixed amount of threads - say 10. I want to have an Execution Queue that executes only business logic section in tasks. That means that once a task is over with its business logic, it will return (the Call method will end).

Comment: Once the task is over, we check if this task is over or it needs to be re-submitted. If it needs to be re-submitted, it needs to sleep according to configuration for that task. I want the Sleep time to occur outside of main Execution Queue threads time.

Comment: Last comment to make it clear - 100 tasks, 10 threads in Execution Queue. Say that the sleep time on task is 3 hours (for example sake) and that I place Thread.sleep for 3 Hours in the Call method, 10 tasks will execute and the rest (90 tasks) will get stuck. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Add a periodic task (`Executors#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` is handy), which will be called every 1 min (or whatever works for you). Once you decide to sleep, put task into a list and have periodic task check that list for tasks which need to be resubmitted.

Comment: Can you write an example? I dont understand how you orchestrate that

Answer (score 1):

This is lengthy, but straight-forward code for illustration of scheduled resubmitter, which I haven't tested :)

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

interface Repeatable {
    boolean shouldBeRepeated();
    /**
     * @return how long to sleep
     */
    long delayBeforeRepeat();

    /**
     * @return "initial" state of this task instance, so this state can be resubmitted for repeated execution
     */
    BusinessTask reset();
}

/**
 * Whatever suits your business logic
 */
interface BusinessTask extends Callable<Repeatable> {
}

class BusinessTaskCompletionData {
    final BusinessTask businessTask;

    /**
     * Timestamp when this task should be resubmitted
     */
    final long nextSubmitTime;

    BusinessTaskCompletionData(BusinessTask businessTask, long nextSubmitTime) {
        this.businessTask = businessTask;
        this.nextSubmitTime = nextSubmitTime;
    }
}

class TaskResusltsConsumer implements Runnable {

    private final CompletionService<Repeatable> completionService;
    private final Deque<BusinessTaskCompletionData> completedTasks;

    TaskResusltsConsumer(ExecutorService executor, Deque<BusinessTaskCompletionData> completedTasks) {
        this.completedTasks = completedTasks;
        completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Future<Repeatable> completedBusinessTask = completionService.take();
                Repeatable repeatable = completedBusinessTask.get();
                if (repeatable.shouldBeRepeated()) {
                    completedTasks.add(new BusinessTaskCompletionData(repeatable.reset(),
                            System.currentTimeMillis() + repeatable.delayBeforeRepeat()));
                }
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ie) {
                // handle somehow
            }
        }
    }
}

class TasksSupplier implements Runnable {

    private final Deque<BusinessTaskCompletionData> completedTasks;
    private final ExecutorService executor;

    TasksSupplier(Deque<BusinessTaskCompletionData> completedTasks, ExecutorService executor) {
        this.completedTasks = completedTasks;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            BusinessTask t = getTaskSomehow();
            executor.submit(getTaskSomehow());
        }
    }

    private BusinessTask getTaskSomehow() {
        // implement
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Actual implementation of logic to obtain 'initial state' of task to repeat and repeat schedule
 */
class BusinessData implements Repeatable {
    // whatever
}

public class SOTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final LinkedList<BusinessTaskCompletionData> tasksToRepeat = new LinkedList<>();

        // workers pool
        final ExecutorService workersPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        // controllers pool: 1 thread for supplier, the other for results consumer
        final ExecutorService controllersPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        controllersPool.submit(new TasksSupplier(tasksToRepeat, workersPool));
        controllersPool.submit(new TaskResusltsConsumer(workersPool, tasksToRepeat));

        // resubmitter scheduled pool
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Iterator<BusinessTaskCompletionData> it = tasksToRepeat.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        BusinessTaskCompletionData data = it.next();
                        if (data.nextSubmitTime >= now) {
                            workersPool.submit(data.businessTask);
                            it.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            // initial delay of 1 sec
            1000,
            // periodic delay of 1 sec
            1000,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        );
    }

}
```